# Why doesn't constant expression give an error?

Tags: c, initialization, c11

If I initialized variable like this:

```
static int i = 2 * 2 / 0;
```

Then, compiler give me an error.

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:23: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
  static int i = 2 * 2 / 0; 
                       ^
prog.c:5:17: error: initializer element is not constant
  static int i = 2 * 2 / 0;
```

But, If I use `||` instead of `*`, like this:

```
static int i = 2 || 2 / 0;
```

then it's successfully compiled.

According to [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), Precedence of `*` higher than `||`. So, first `2 / 0` operation evaluated. Am I right?

So, why doesn't `static int i = 2 || 2 / 0;` give an error?

Comment: `||` is short circuiting, so the second part of the expression isn't evaluated at all.

Comment: @Groo: Answers in the answers section please.

Comment: more interesting is to ask whether `a || 2 / 0` gives an error...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Maybe not for the division, but for the non-constant initialiser,

Comment: @Olaf naturally I mean an auto variable. And wb :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The question uses `static`, I assumed that too, of course. But the warning (it is not an error) is not mandated by the standard, div-zero is simply UB and at run-time it **typically** depends on whether the architecture generates an exception. FYI: gcc warns about `2 / 0` for `auto` variables, independent of the value of `a`, even without warning options.

Comment: Precedence only determines which operands are grouped with which operators - it *does not* determine order of evaluation.  `||` and `&&` always evaluate left to right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to the mandatory short-circuit evaluation of `||` and the fact that your expression is evaluated as

```
static int i = (2 || (2 / 0));
```

Because `2` is an expression equal to `2`, `2 / 0` is not evaluated.

Comment: And important detail is, `||` etc are *guaranteed* to be short-circuiting.